# how to add sorting orderby using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, entity, sql-order-by

I am using entity framework to develop asp.net website(C#)
with SQL database I have column[FromMonth] saving string data Type (not int),  how to add order by  with that sort order
{ Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec } descending
please help

```
 List< TblExperince > experince =(from x in db.TblExperince
                           where x.id_main == IDmain
                           orderby x.FromYear descending[,x.FromMonth ??]
                             select x).ToList();
```

I found the solution by adding new table to my .edmx model for ordering months and its work

```
  List<TblExperince> experince = (from x in db.TblExperince
                                  join o in db.TblMonthOrder  on x.FromMonth  equals o.MonthName 
                                  where x.id_main == IDmain
                                  orderby x.FromYear descending,o.MonthNo descending 
                                  select x).ToList();
```

Comment: More headache than it's probably worth! Store month name and value in another table and then order it by that value.

Comment: Actually I already used related table in my work but it's my first time using entity framework and I wont to get familiar with it , I found the solution by adding new table to my .edmx model and its work , thanks for hint